# Will an Arduino Uno be able to read 3x incremental encoders?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, arduino-due, rotary-encoder

Encoders are quadrature 600ppr encoders with X2 counting. Therefore 1200 counts per revolution for each encoder. Is there an edge rate limit? I currently have one encoder hooked up using code with interrupts.

Comment: The answer to the title's question is likely yes.  But I think your real question is how fast can (and you need to name a specific platform) a 16MHz Arduino Uno read a GPIO pin.

Comment: How fast are the encoders rotating?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of some code I used to read two encoders using pin change interrupts.  This is possible to do with one ISR since they all share a common port.  The key is it has to be short.  As long as you can keep all 6 pins from your encoder on the same port, this should be easy to extend to 3 encoders.  It might even work for four on one port.  Or you can make a use a second port and get 3 or 4 more depending on which chip you have.

```
volatile uint8_t lastPortRead = 0;

volatile int32_t leftCounter = 0;
volatile int32_t rightCounter = 0;


ISR(PCINT2_vect){

    uint8_t portRead = PINC;

    uint8_t whoFired = portRead ^ lastPortRead;
    uint8_t pinsDiff = portRead ^ (portRead << 1); // Will have bits 5 or 7 set if pins on right motor or left motor are diff.  Cleared if same.

    if (whoFired & LEFT_INT_MASK) {
        if (pinsDiff & LEFT_INT_MASK) {
            leftCounter++;
        } else {
            leftCounter--;
        }
    }
    if (whoFired & RIGHT_INT_MASK) {
        if (pinsDiff & RIGHT_INT_MASK) {
            rightCounter++;
        } else {
            rightCounter--;
        }
    }

    lastPortRead = portRead;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title's question is likely yes. But it would appear the real question is how fast can a given Arduino read a GPIO pin.

Consider there are multiple Arduino platforms.  Each possibly using a different type of processors.  Likely those processors are running at different speeds.  To give a specific answer we need to assume a specific platform, processor and speed.  The [current (3rd generation) Arduino Uno runs at 16MHz](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3).  And the [Arduino Due runs at 84Mhz](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/due).  Since most people use an Arduino Uno let us use it for an example.

In [this arduino.cc forum thread](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=337578.0) it is commented that an Arduino Uno running at 16MHz can execute the "Digital Pin Read" function call in about 4.78us.  Rounding that up to 5us that would be 1/5E-6 or 200000 samples per second.  Likely this can be improved upon if code were written to directly control the processors register for the desired outcome.  This is usually considered a moderately difficult embedded programming task.  And well outside normal Arduino knowledge.  In addition, such code would likely no longer be portable between different Arduino platforms.

Comment: there are tags arduino-uno and arduino-due on the question and Uno is in the title. so why the intro?

Comment: Good point.  I usually use tags for searching.  Didn't occur to me that tags were used to frame the question.  I'll reword the answer.

Comment: and that is in microseconds not milliseconds for digitalRead. "A digitalRead() is about 3.6us. "

Comment: You are correct.  Looking through that forum thread I only see the reference for 4.78us.  I edited the answer again and removed the mistake.

Comment: so "Will an Arduino Uno be able to read 3x incremental encoders?" (parallel)

Comment: Probably.  Or, to put it another way, it would appear unlikely the encoder would create more than 100000 cycles per second.